# Using Http::post to get data from API

Tags: laravel, api, http-post, laravel-7

I tried to get data from API, when in Postman it's working fine but when i tried it in laravel it return an error

[image: Postman Result]

How do i get that data to laravel?

This is from my controller :

```
$response = Http::post('https://url.id/api/tryout/check', [
                'category_id' => 0,
                'platform' => 'platform',
                'is_unique' => false,
                'chapters' => [
                    'id' => 3,
                    'name' => "Aljabar",
                    'count' => 10,
                ],
        ]);

return $response;
```

But the code above will return an error :

```
Trying to access array offset on value of type int
```

Comment: Check the category_id in request object becuase in both code there is a difference in category_id with 0 and 1.

Comment: @NIKUNJPATEL changing it from 0 to 1 still produce the same error

Comment: @SaberBlade what line exactly trigger the error ?

Comment: @N69S [link](https://ibb.co/Stn6yS5)

Comment: show us dd($chapter) pls, in foreach

Comment: Your question is missing the code related to your error (TryoutController) and some debugging of the variable `$chapters` or `$req->getContent()`. Please [edit] your question and add all relevant details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are passing your `chapters` data as array of object in your POSTMAN,

```
"chapters": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        ..
        ..
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        ..
        ..
    }
]
```

then its a plain object in your Laravel HTTP request, which throwing an error because you are looping through `id`, `name` and `count` and not through an object containing those key which your loop expects to have

```
"chapters": {
    "id": 3,
        ..
        ..
}
```

you need this part to be a list of objects

```
'chapters' => [
    'id' => 3,
    ..
],
```

should be

```
'chapters' => [
    [ 
        'id' => 3,
        ..
    ]
],
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You are sending `'category_id' => 0` I don’t believe that it exists in your database. You have to change it to `'category_id' => 1`
2. And also you have to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75482894/11287544) answer too.